# 3Gs after 5.0.1 upgrade, all third-party apps can not open and work

Tags: ios

After iPhone 3Gs upgrade iOS to 5.0.1, all third-party apps can not open and work. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  Delete one app, then add it back.